# Create a polygon around a line

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing

I have a line represented as an array of X,Y coordinates.  I am displaying this on screen via a HTML5 canvas and want to provide user interactions.  To this end I need to see if a users mouse is on the line to provide visual feedback and allow them to move it etc.

The line is displayed as a "line" with stroke giving it a thickness so just checking that the mouse is "on" the line wouldn't work very well as it would be hard for the user to be exactly over the line.

For this reason I want to create a polygon around the line (essentially adding padding).  This would mean a user didnt have to be directly on the line, just very close to it.  I would then use this polygon for hit-tests.

How do I go about turning a list of points (my line) into a polygon that represents that line with padding? (say 10px).

```
points: [
    { x: -200, y: 150 },
    { x: -100, y: 50 },
    { x: 100, y: 50 },
    { x: 200, y: 150 }
]
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823504/polygon-from-polyline/23825086#23825086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a polygon around the line (essentially adding
> padding). This would mean a user didnt have to be directly on the
> line, just very close to it. I would then use this polygon for
> hit-tests.

You don't need to go through the math to achieve this, simply use the built-in `isPointInStroke()` and set a `lineWidth` and `lineCap` beforehand to increase "sensitivity" (just use this [polyfill](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) for `isPointInStroke()` for users who uses IE, or take the harder route vie the math as in f.ex. the [link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823504/polygon-from-polyline/23825086#23825086) by @Mbo).

You can store the path as [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) objects and do hit-test with those, or build a current path and set `lineWidth` for that to do tests with. Note that the path you want to test need to be rebuilt if not the current path.

### Example

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    points = [
     { x: 10, y: 120 },
     { x: 110, y: 20 },
     { x: 310, y: 20 },
     { x: 410, y: 120 }
    ];

// create current path and draw polyline
createPath(points);
ctx.stroke();

// increase "padding" and for demo, show area
ctx.lineWidth = 20;      // padded area to evaluate
ctx.lineCap = "round";   // caps of line, incl. to evaluate

ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200,0,0,0.2)";  // not needed, for demo only
ctx.stroke();

// for sensing mouse
c.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var r = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = e.clientX - r.left,
      y = e.clientY - r.top;
  info.innerHTML = ctx.isPointInStroke(x, y) ? "HIT" : "Outside";
};

// build path
function createPath(points) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for(var i = 1, p; p = points[i++];) ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600></canvas><br><div id=info></div>
```

Comment: Hi, this looks great (and simple) but how would it work if I had multiple lines?

Comment: @Chris just rebuild each path you want to check (no need to actually draw them - you would do that initially of course, but not when checking for hits), or store each path in a Path2D object. isPointInStroke() as well as stroke() can take a Path2D objects as argument. To rebuilt without using Path2D, use beginPath(), build path, check, repeat for next path.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I stumbled across that after writing my comment and have implemented it successfully :)

Answer (score 2):

**Option#1:** You could draw a polygon around the line making it a "fat target".

**Option#2:** You could use `isPointInStroke` to hit-test the stroke.

**Option#3: A purely mathematical alternative.**

Math has the advantage of being cross-browser compatible (`isPointInStroke` fails on IE/Edge).

**Here's how....**

Calculate the distance from the mouse to the closest point on the line.

```
// find XY on line closest to mouse XY
// line shape: {x0:,y0:,x1:,y1:}
// mouse position: mx,my
function closestXY(line,mx,my){
    var x0=line.x0;
    var y0=line.y0;
    var x1=line.x1;
    var y1=line.y1;
    var dx=x1-x0;
    var dy=y1-y0;
    var t=((mx-x0)*dx+(my-y0)*dy)/(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    t=Math.max(0,Math.min(1,t));
    var x=lerp(x0,x1,t);
    var y=lerp(y0,y1,t);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// linear interpolation -- needed in closestXY()
function lerp(a,b,x){return(a+x*(b-a));}
```

If that distance is within your 10px "hit range" then then that line is selected.

```
// is the mouse within 10px of the line
var hitTolerance=10;
var dx=mx-closestPt.x;
var dy=my-closestPt.y;
var distance=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
if(distance<=hitTolerance){
    // this line is w/in 10px of the mouse
}
```

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// dragging vars
var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

// points
var points=[
    { x: 0,   y: 150 },
    { x: 100, y: 50 },
    { x: 300, y: 50 },
    { x: 500, y: 150 }
]

// create lines from points
var lines=[];
for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    lines.push({
        x0:points[i-1].x,
        y0:points[i-1].y,
        x1:points[i].x,
        y1:points[i].y,
    });
}

// if the mouse is within 10px of a line, it's selected
var hitTolerance=10;

// just an efficiency to avoid the expensive Math.sqrt
var hitToleranceSquared=hitTolerance*hitTolerance;

// on mousedown, "nearest" holds any line w/in 10px of the mouse
var nearest=null;

// draw the scene for the first time
draw();

// listen for mouse events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});


// functions
//////////////////////////

// select the nearest line to the mouse
function closestLine(mx,my){
    var dist=100000000;
    var index,pt;
    // test the mouse vs each line -- find the closest line
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        // find the XY point on the line that's closest to mouse
        var xy=closestXY(lines[i],mx,my);
        //
        var dx=mx-xy.x;
        var dy=my-xy.y;
        var thisDist=dx*dx+dy*dy;
        if(thisDist<dist){
            dist=thisDist;
            pt=xy;
            index=i;            
        }
    }
    // test if the closest line is within the hit distance
    if(dist<=hitToleranceSquared){
        var line=lines[index];
        return({ pt:pt, line:line, originalLine:{x0:line.x0,y0:line.y0,x1:line.x1,y1:line.y1} });
    }else{
        return(null);
    }
}

// linear interpolation -- needed in setClosestLine()
function lerp(a,b,x){return(a+x*(b-a));}

// find closest XY on line to mouse XY
function closestXY(line,mx,my){
    var x0=line.x0;
    var y0=line.y0;
    var x1=line.x1;
    var y1=line.y1;
    var dx=x1-x0;
    var dy=y1-y0;
    var t=((mx-x0)*dx+(my-y0)*dy)/(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    t=Math.max(0,Math.min(1,t));
    var x=lerp(x0,x1,t);
    var y=lerp(y0,y1,t);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// draw the scene
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // draw all lines at their current positions
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        drawLine(lines[i],'black');
    }
    // draw markers if a line is being dragged
    if(nearest){
        // point on line nearest to mouse
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(nearest.pt.x,nearest.pt.y,5,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.strokeStyle='red';
        ctx.stroke();
        // marker for original line before dragging
        drawLine(nearest.originalLine,'red');
        // hightlight the line as its dragged
        drawLine(nearest.line,'red');
    }
}

function drawLine(line,color){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line.x0,line.y0);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x1,line.y1);
    ctx.strokeStyle=color;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // mouse position
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // find nearest line to mouse
  nearest=closestLine(startX,startY);
  // set dragging flag if a line was w/in hit distance
  if(nearest){
      isDown=true;
      draw();
  }
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // clear dragging flag
  isDown=false;
  nearest=null;
  draw();
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
    if(!isDown){return;}
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // mouse position
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // calc how far mouse has moved since last mousemove event
    var dx=mouseX-startX;
    var dy=mouseY-startY;
    startX=mouseX;
    startY=mouseY;
    // change nearest line vertices by distance moved
    var line=nearest.line;
    line.x0+=dx;
    line.y0+=dy;
    line.x1+=dx;
    line.y1+=dy;
    // redraw
    draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag lines with mouse.<br>You must start drag within 10px of line</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=550 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP meant this

Comment: @K3N. Yep, `isPointInPath` is a good option. :-) Currently it needs a shim but (hopefully) Microsoft will soon fully join the "modern browser" club -- it appears they're trying to join.

Answer (score 1):

## Lines, Line Segments, and points near by.

For the Math involved there are two functions to help,

**Distance point to line.**

The following function finds the distance from a point to a line.

```
// return distance of point (px,py) to line ((l1x,l1y),(l2x,l2y))
distPoint2Line = function(px, py, l1x, l1y, l2x, l2y){
    var v1x,v1y,v2x,v2y,l,c;
    v1x = l2x - l1x;  // convert the line to a vector basicly moves the line 
    v1y = l2y - l1y;  // so that it starts at 0,0
    v2x = px - l1x;  // shift the point the same distance so it is in the 
    v2y = py - l1y;  // same relative position
    // Useful math trick 
    // The following finds the unit length of the closest point 
    // on the line vector V1 to the point v2
    // u is unbounded and can have any value but if it is 
    // 0 <= u <= 1 then that point is on the line where 
    // where u = 0 is the start u = 0.5 the middle and u = 1 the end
    // u < 0 is before the line start and u > 1 is after the line end
    // in math gargon. Get the dot product of V2 . V1 divided by the length squared of V1
    u = (v2x * v1x + v2y * v1y)/(v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y);
    // Now if we multiply the vector of the line V1 by c we get the
    // coordinates of the closest point on the line
    v1x *= u;
    v1y *= u;
    // now it is simple to find the distance from that point on the 
    // line to the point via pythagoras
    v1x -= v2x;  // distance between the two points
    v1y -= v2y;
    // sqrt of the sum of the square of the sides 
    return Math.sqrt(v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y);
}
```

**Distance point to line segment**

You now have a distance that the point is to the line, but the problem is that a line is unbounded and has infinite length. We want to find the distance from the line segment that has a clear start, end and length.

If you read the comments in the code above you will see that we have all we need in that function already. Specifically the unit distance u if we clamp that value (keep it so that 0 <= u <= 1) the above function will give us the distance from the line segment, if the point moves past the start or end the distance will be from the start or end point whichever is closest.

```
// return distance of point (px,py) to line ((l1x,l1y),(l2x,l2y))
distPoint2Line = function(px, py, l1x, l1y, l2x, l2y){
    var v1x,v1y,v2x,v2y,l,c;
    v1x = l2x - l1x;  // convert the line to a vector basicly moves the line 
    v1y = l2y - l1y;  // so that it starts at 0,0
    v2x = px - l1x;  // shift the point the same distance so it is in the 
    v2y = py - l1y;  // same relative position
    // get unit distance
    u = (v2x * v1x + v2y * v1y)/(v1x * v1x + v2x * v2x);
    // clamp it
    u = Math.max(0,Math.Min(1,u)); // if below 0 make it 0 if above 1 make it 1
    v1x *= u;   // multiply the line vector
    v1y *= u;
    v1x -= v2x;  // distance between the two points x and y components
    v1y -= v2y;
    // sqrt of the sum of the square of the sides gives the distance
    return Math.sqrt(v1x,v1y);
}
```

**When is a line not a line?**

There are some conditions where a line as described by two points (valid numbers) is not a line we can deal with. A line with zero length (both end and start point are at the same coordinate) and an infinite line segment where one or both points are at infinity

**A point with a start and an End**

What to do when a line is passed to the function where the end and start are at the same point. When this happens the line segment length is 0 and because we divide by the square of 0 (0*0 is still 0) Javascript returns Infinity and from there things start to get messy and the return value is `NaN` (not a number). So what to do. We cant leave it as `NaN` as that is a mind f..k in Javascript and nothing equals `NaN` (not even `NaN == NaN`) so you would have to call yet another function. All too long winded and unsuited to the problem.

Another way to deal with it is to return `undefined` or `null` but again this is a terrible solution as it means that whenever you use the function you have to vet its results.

If you think about the unit distance `u`. `Infinity` is the correct answer, but we don't know the direction the line is traveling, but we do know one point in 2D space where the line is so returning the distance to that point does fit the constraints and allows for a meaningful result that can be trusted to be a number.

So there is a little mod to the code

```
   u = (v1x * v1x + v2x * v2x);
   u = u === 0 ? 0 : (v2x * v1x + v2y * v1y) / u;   // if u is 0 then set it as 0
```

This will then flow on to give a result that is the distance from the infinitely small and directionless line segment described by the line ((l1x,l1y),(l2x,l2y)) and in context of the question has a valued and correct meaning.

The same is done for the line segment

**An infinitely long line segment**

It can happen that the results of some calculations set the coordinates of one or both the start and end at `Infinity` or `-Infinity`, and it may be just one coordinate x, or y. When this happens we end up with `NaN` straight away.

We can deal with it by vetting all the points coming into the function. But this is for the vast majority of situations unneeded overhead. I will ignore this situation and this is just to let people know that it is possible in some situations and that vetting should be done if you feel you need to be safe.

Now we don't have to vet every result of the function and can trust it has meaning applicable to finding a distance from a line.

**A word on compatibility**

One last thing is browser compatibility. In the new (well year old) ES6 (ECMAScript 6) there is the math function `Math.hypot` that returns the hypotenuse of a set of coordinates 2D,3D,...,nD It is such a useful function and is so much quicker than `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2))` that I have personally decided not to ignore it. Thus I provide a polyfill that covers the 2D needs of this problem, for a better solution I leave it up to you to find one on the net. If this is not your policy then replace all `Math.hypot(x,y)` with `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2))`

**Wrap it up**

So now to clean it all up into a useful package

This has

- **lineHelper.distPoint2Line(px, py, l1x, l1y, l2x, l2y)** returns the distance the point (px,py) is from the line ((l1x, l1y), (l2x, l2y))
- **lineHelper.distPoint2LineSeg(px, py, l1x, l1y, l2x, l2y)** same as above but to the line segment rather than the line
- **lineHelper.indexOfLineClosest2Point(px, py, array, closed)** Find the closest line segment to the point (px, py) where array one
  dimensional array as a set of points describing the lines [p1x, p1y,
  p2x, p2y, ... , pnx, pny]. closed is optional and if not false will
  consider the end and start points in the array are a line segment as
  well thus closing the path. The index is the absolute index from 0
  for the first point, 2 for the second  and (n-1)*2 for the last
  point. The returned value will always be even or 0.
- **lineHelper.getPointOnLine()** As the results of the above calculations the point on the line is stored and can be retrieved
  with this call. It will return an array of two numbers representing
  the coordinate on the line segment ie [x,y]. For lines this point may
  be outside the line segment. for lines this point will be on the line
  or at the start or end point. If at the end point it may be out by
  the floating point errors inherent in this type of math. Use
  `Math.EPSILON` to check if this is at the end or the following
  function to see if unit distance is 1
- **lineHelper.getUnitDist()** As a result of calculations returns the unit distance along the line that is the closest point on the line to
  the point given in calculations. It is clamped for line segments and
  unclamped for lines. If the line/line segment is a point the it will
  be 0. This is not valid for `indexOfLineClosest2Point` and may
  be any value.
- **lineHelper.getMinDist()** As the result of the function `indexOfLineClosest2Point` this function will return the distance to the line segment found by that function. This value is only valid after the call to `indexOfLineClosest2Point` and until the function is called again.

And the code

```
var lineHelper = (function(){ // call it what you want
    var hypot = Math.hypot;
    if(typeof hypot !== "function"){ // poly fill for hypot
         hypot = function(x,y){
            return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
         }
    }
    var lenSq, unitDist, minDist, v1x, v1y, v2x, v2y, lsx, lsy, vx,vy; // closure vars
    var dP2L = function(px, py, l1x, l1y, l2x, l2y){
        v1x = l2x - l1x; 
        v1y = l2y - l1y;  
        v2x = px - (lsx = l1x);  
        v2y = py - (lsy = l1y);  
        unitDist = (v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y);
        unitDist = unitDist === 0 ? 0 : (v2x * v1x + v2y * v1y) / unitDist;
        return hypot((v1x *= unitDist) - v2x, (v1y *= unitDist) - v2y);
    }
    var dP2LS = function(px, py, l1x, l1y, l2x, l2y){
        v1x = l2x - l1x; 
        v1y = l2y - l1y;  
        v2x = px - (lsx = l1x);  
        v2y = py - (lsy = l1y);  
        unitDist = (v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y);
        unitDist = unitDist === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (v2x * v1x + v2y * v1y) / unitDist));
        return hypot((v1x *= unitDist) - v2x, (v1y *= unitDist) - v2y);
    }
    var dP2V = function(px, py, l1x, l1y){  // point dist to vector
        unitDist = (l1x * l1x + l1y * l1y);
        unitDist = unitDist === 0 ? 0 : unitDist = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (px * l1x + py * l1y) / unitDist));
        return hypot((v1x = l1x * unitDist) - px, (v1y = l1y * unitDist) - py);
    }
    var cLineSeg = function(px, py, array, closed){
         var i, len, leni, dist, lineIndex;
         minDist = Infinity;
         leni = len = array.length;
         if(! closed){
            leni -= 2;
         }
         for(i = 0; i < leni; i += 2){
            dist = dP2V(px - array[i], py - array[i + 1], array[(i + 2) % len] - array[i], array[(i + 3) % len] - array[i +1]);
            if(dist < minDist){
                lineIndex = i;
                minDist = dist;
                lsx = array[i];
                lsy = array[i + 1];
                vx = v1x;
                vy = v1y;
            }
         }
         v1x = vx;
         v1y = vy;
         return lineIndex;
    }
    return {
        distPoint2Line : dP2L,
        distPoint2LineSeg : dP2LS,
        indexOfLineClosest2Point : cLineSeg,
        getPointOnLine : function(){ return [lsx + v1x,lsy + v1y] },
        getUnitDist : function() { return unitDist; },
        getMinDist : function() { return minDist; },
   }
})();
```